# Unwanted Text, when using the Nucleic Acid Research LaTeX template

Tags: header-footer, templates

I am fairly new to the world of LaTeX, but I really want to give it an honest try, since many people have recommended to use it. Therefore i wanted to try to format a paper for the journal nucleic acid research (NAR). They have a nice template on their website, but unfortunately, I have some problems with it. Especially the unwanted header is problematic. I can't figure out, where the origin of this is, since I don't have any "nonexisting" figures in my document and it appears even, when I compile the .tex file directly after downloading without any changes to it.

I tried different compilers, but work mostly with the TeXstudio and MiKTeX package.

Does anybody have an idea, where this might come from or how I could possibly correct it?

Thanks in advance
Stefan

PS: I have uploaded the output PDF for me as a picture. The template can be found here https://academic.oup.com/nar/pages/ms_prep_submission.

[image: Output of my the template for me]

Comment: The link seems to be broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite curious that the ZIP file provides a very outdated version of `crop.sty` (1.6, released 2001/11/16), when the current version of `crop.sty` is 1.10, released 2017/11/19.

If I remove `crop.sty` from the working directory in which I unzipped the provided file, the output is correct as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! That solved the problem!